# telegram bot don't answer

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I add ssl certificates from certbot. And try to use this [example](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/webhook_examples/webhook_flask_echo_bot.py) with my token, port, url and others.
I run script and then check state with this link `https://api.telegram.org/bot827929874:AAELa-Dl6pYFM_test_test/getWebhookInfo` and get this answer `{"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://my_site.com:88/827929874:AAELa-Dl6pYFM_test_test/","has_custom_certificate":true,"pending_update_count":32,"max_connections":40}}`. I see that now 32 messages is in a queue waiting. Why bot didn't response?

UPD:
Rewrite nginx config to:

```
server{
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}



    listen 80; # managed by Certbot

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.comprivkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Change port to 443 in python script. Still same error `Connection timed out` if do request on `https://api.telegram.org/bot<Token>`
Telegram's api has ping from server.